# VBA, Dealing with E-10

Tags: excel, vba

I have cells that are supposed to be `0` I believe. `7.45058059692383E-12`.
How do I make these 0 in my code?

```
Sheets("MainData").Range("C" & i) = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("C" & i)
```

I thought converting `NumberFormat` to `0` may help but it did not work.

```
Sheets("MainData").Range("C" & i) = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("C" & i).NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

Instead the result is `FALSE`

Please Help!

**Full code:**

```
Sub CopyData()

Worksheets("MainData").Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

'Copy data from the CM Commentary File to Template
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
Set MainDataCM = Workbooks.Open(Sheets("Input").Range("B3") & Sheets("Input").Range("B6"))
MainDataCM.Sheets("Main Data").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
MainDataCM.Close savechanges:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Sheets("Main Data").Name = "CM_MainData"

Worksheets("CM_MainData").Visible = False

'Read the CM_MainData tab and copy the required columns in the MainData tab
Dim k As Long
k = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("A1", Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Debug.Print (k)

i = 2

While i <= k
    Sheets("MainData").Range("A" & i) = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("A" & i)
    Sheets("MainData").Range("B" & i) = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("B" & i)
    Sheets("MainData").Range("C" & i) = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("C" & i).NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Sheets("MainData").Range("D" & i) = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("D" & i)
    Sheets("MainData").Range("E" & i) = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("C" & i) * 1000
    Sheets("MainData").Range("F" & i) = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("H" & i)
    'Sheets("MainData").Range("E" & i).NumberFormat = "0.00"
    
    If Sheets("MainData").Range("F" & i) = "" Then
        Sheets("MainData").Range("F" & i) = "RBC INVESTOR SERV O/H & MISC"
    End If
    
    i = i + 1
    
Wend

Worksheets("Macro").Activate
Worksheets("Macro").Select

MsgBox "Step 1 Completed"

End Sub
```

Comment: Why? I am transferring data from one sheet to another. As I transfer it I want to deal with these `E-12` numbers.

Comment: `Sheets("MainData").Range("C" & i) = Round(Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("C" & i),2)`

Comment: remember that changing the number format does not change the value in the cell only how it is displayed.  by rounding the value as you insert it will input the value rounded.

Comment: THANKS SCOTTY. Can I round it to more decimal places?

Comment: yes, just change the `2` to the number of decimals desired.

Answer (score 4):

Value transfer:

```
Sheets("MainData").Range("C" & i).Value = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("C" & i).Value
```

Number format (a separate step, and *does not change the underlying value*):

```
Sheets("MainData").Range("C" & i).NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

Or use `WorksheetFunction.Round` (*does change the underlying value*).

```
Sheets("MainData").Range("C" & i).Value = WorksheetFunction.Round(Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("C" & i).Value, 2)
```